# SQL Server Query group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written Query. Below is that query

```
SELECT
  COUNT(amount) AS NR_Sales,
  DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) AS years
FROM c_Payment_service_fee
WHERE CFK_F_key IN (SELECT
  FK_2290F_key
FROM C_Submissions
WHERE FK_C_UP_key IN (SELECT
  PK_C_UP_key
FROM C_User_Profile
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND (DATEPART(WEEK, @date)))
AND DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND (DATEPART(WEEK, @date)))
AND DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND (DATEPART(WEEK, @date))
AND amount > 0
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt)
```

And one more

```
SELECT
  amount AS NR_Sales,
  DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) AS years
FROM c_Payment_service_fee
WHERE CFK_F_key IN (SELECT
  FK_2290F_key
FROM C_Submissions
WHERE FK_C_UP_key IN (SELECT
  PK_C_UP_key
FROM C_User_Profile
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND (DATEPART(WEEK, @date))
AND DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) = 2019)
AND DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) = 2019
AND DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND (DATEPART(WEEK, @date)))
AND DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND (DATEPART(WEEK, @date))
AND amount > 0
AND DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) = 2019
```

Both are working fine no error. But my problem is if i run first query 2019 count will be 303 and if run second query 269 data is displaying of 2019 year.

Where I making mistaking i am not able find the problem please help me with that.

Comment: Please format your queries so that we may read them.  We should not have to do that for you.

Comment: Please put the sample data and expected output and schema also if possible.

Comment: *"if run second query run 2019 count will be 269."* What `COUNT`? You don't have that function in your second query. Also, why have you tagged both SQL Server 2008 and 2012?

Comment: For the first query, you have the `COUNT(PK_C_PSF_key) AS NR_Sales`, but for the second one you have `amount` **AS NR_Sales**, so there is no count for the second one you just give the `amount` column _NR_Sales_ alias. So the short answer to your question is: _Because there is no COUNT() in the second query_.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
PK_C_UP_key
FROM C_User_Profile
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 
(DATEPART(WEEK, @date))
AND DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) = 2019
```

is more restrictive than

```
SELECT
PK_C_UP_key
FROM C_User_Profile
WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, crn_dt) BETWEEN 1 AND 
(DATEPART(WEEK, @date))
```

So, the FK_C_UP_key could take more values from  subquery in your first query.

Comment: My answer is 269 is correct only. But when i add group by clause it is showing 303 count

Comment: You are right, but if you restrict to 2019 in the first subquery (AND DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) = 2019), the results from the two query will be the same.

Comment: the conditions are not equivalent because you take more CFK_F_key in the first query

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
  COUNT(amount) AS NR_Sales,
  DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) AS years
FROM c_Payment_service_fee
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt)

Answer (score 0):

You first query has:

```
SELECT COUNT(amount) AS NR_Sales, DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) AS years
```

Your second has:

```
SELECT amount AS NR_Sales, DATEPART(YEAR, crn_dt) AS years
```

Your are comparing the count of rows to the sum of a column.  I'm not surprised they are different.

I don't know what you want, but I would recommend using this for both queries:

```
SELECT YEAR(crn_dt), COUNT(*) as num_rows,
       SUM(amount) as total_amount
```